# Android: Refresh App using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i use the AlarmManager to fire off an Intent at midnight, which loads an ArrayList and does some modifications on its items. The problem is, i have a Fragment, which saves its version of the ArrayList in onPause(). What i want is, 
for the Fragments to reload the ArrayList from SharedPreferences when the Alarm Intent goes off and also to update the Views. 
In other words, i want to reload the Fragment without it visible close/restart of the app.

Can anyone tell me how i can do that from my Receiver class?

```
public class DayCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private ArrayList<TaskItem> mTaskList;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //load
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TASKLIST_FILE, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TaskItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    mTaskList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (mTaskList != null && mTaskList.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTaskList.size(); i++) {
            mTaskList.get(i).shiftDayChecks();
            mTaskList.get(i).resetTimeLeft();
        }
    }


    //save
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    gson = new Gson();
    json = gson.toJson(mTaskList);
    editor.putString(TASKLIST_FILE, json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have to reload the array list in a fragment since you want it to be done in the background, the only way I know is for you to use service. Since the data are stored in shared preference as you said, you can always refer to it from a service

Comment: Your question is about that fragment is visible to the user at the time of the alarm.  ?

Comment: The Fragment may be visible or not. The action on the ArrayList has to be performed around this time. But if the user has the app opened, i want the UI to refresh when the changes are made.